# Dynamics 365 Passing Regarding Entity Type to a Form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, powerapps-modeldriven

I am passing following parameter to a form

```
var parameters = {};  
    //Set the Parent Customer field value to “Contoso”.  
    parameters["regardingobjectid"] = orderID;  
    parameters["regardingobjectidname"] = formContext.getAttribute("name").getValue();
    parameters["regardingobjectidentitytype"] = "salesorder";
    
  
    // Define the entity name to open the form  
    var entityFormOptions = {};
    entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "email";
    entityFormOptions["formId"] = "GUID";  

    // Open the form
    Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, parameters).then(
        function (success) {
            console.log(success);
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

However, following line of codes doesn't work as it sets the entity type to default one which account instead of Sales Order

```
 parameters["regardingobjectid"] = orderID;  
    parameters["regardingobjectidname"] = formContext.getAttribute("name").getValue();
    parameters["regardingobjectidentitytype"] = "salesorder";
```

What will be the parameter I need to set for the Entity Type here?

Comment: In your code above `***parameters["regardingobjectidentitytype"] = "salesorder";***` Is this commented? This should not be commented. In addition your orderID does this return Guid as string?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. It should be `regardingobjectidtype` and not `regardingobjectidentitytype`. This will setup the “regarding” lookup as sales order record in opened email form. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openform?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#example-3-open-a-form-for-new-record-complex-lookup)

```
parameters["regardingobjectidtype"] = "salesorder"; // Table name.
```